# regex: Extract int after string and colon

Tags: c++, regex

I have a string that has the form `" \"one\":\"1\", \"two\":2, \"three\":3, \"two\":22 "`. I am trying to extract all the value that come after the string `"two":`, i.e., in the above case I want to extract `2` and `22`.

Here is my work so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    const std::string str = " \"one\":\"1\", \"two\": 2, \"three\":3, \"two\":22 ";

    std::regex rgx("\"two\":([0-9]*)");
    std::smatch match;

    std::regex_search(str.begin(), str.end(), match, rgx);
    std::cout << "match[0] = " << match[0] << '\n';
}
```

This gives the output `"two"`, so my expression `rgx` is wrong. What is the correct form I need to use?

EDIT: Note there is no whitespace between colons and what comes to the right of it.

Comment: First of all: `rgx("\"two\":([0-9]*)")` This fails to find the whitespace you have between `two:` and `2`.

Comment: @DimChtz Thanks, that was an error on my part -- there's not supposed to be a whitespace.

Comment: Try this one: `std::regex rgx("\"two\":(.?)");` Unfortunately, I can't test it right now.

Comment: @DimChtz This gives me two matches: `"two":2` and `2`

Comment: Your regex is correct, just grab group 1 value (`match[1]`). To get all matches use `sregex_iterator`. `regex_search` will only fetch you a single (first)  match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is correct, just grab group 1 value (`match[1]`). To get all matches use `sregex_iterator`. `regex_search` will only fetch you a single (first) match.

You may use

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
    std::regex r("\"two\":([0-9]*)"); 
    std::vector<int> results;
    std::string s = " \"one\":\"1\", \"two\":2, \"three\":3, \"two\":22 ";
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
            i != std::sregex_iterator(); 
            ++i) 
    { 
        std::smatch m = *i; 
        results.push_back(std::stoi( m[1].str().c_str() ));
    } 
    for (auto n: results)
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/FFZLD1).

Note that you need to get the pointer to the char array when you convert the string to an integer with `std::stoi( m[1].str().c_str() )`, that is [what `.c_str()` does](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

Comment: How can I convert the value `m[1]` to an integer and insert it in, e.g., a `std::vector<int>`? I tried with `std::stoi( m[1].str() )`, but this gives me `invalid_argument` for the call to `stoi`

Comment: @N08: [Here is a way to push the converted strings to numbers to a vector](https://ideone.com/FFZLD1).

Answer (score 1):

Could also write it this way:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::string s = " \"one\":\"1\", \"two\":2, \"two\":44, \"three\":3, \"two\":22 ";

    for (std::smatch m; std::regex_search(s, m, std::regex("\"two\":(\\d+)")); s = m.suffix())
    {
        std::cout << m[1] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```